# Draw SKPolyline underneath street labels

Tags: skmaps

I'm currently trying our the Skobbler Maps API for our app.  I am adding an SKPolyline (in Swift) using:

```
self.mapView.addPolyline(polyline)
```

However, the polyline covers over all street labels.  The polyline is drawn over the street labels even if I change the drawing mode in the map settings to  DrawableObjectsOverAnnotations.

Is there any way to draw the polylines underneath the street labels?   We'd like to keep the street labels visible to the users, for safety and usability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible - all polylines & polygons are drawn over the map features